# Jquery mouseover/mouseout IE8 Fluctuations

Tags: jquery, debugging, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, nav

I have a Jquery menu that dispays the subnav using jquery .addclass and .css. I am adding classes and manipulating the css with mouseover and mouseout. In Firefox, Chrome and Safari everything works fine but in IE8 it seems to "flicker" between the classes.

It's hard to explain but if you look at my link in FF and IE you'll see what I mean.

http://trustmarkstaging.com/

Here's my jQuery:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#nav .item-466").mouseover(function(){
 $("#selector").addClass("item-466-selector");
 $("#nav .menu .current ul li").css("display", "none");
 $("#nav .menu .active ul li").css("display", "none");
 $("#nav .menu .item-466 ul li").addClass("highlight");
});
$("#nav .item-466").mouseout(function(){
 $("#selector").removeClass("item-466-selector");
 $("#nav .menu .current ul li").css("display", "inline");
 $("#nav .menu .active ul li").css("display", "inline");
 $("#nav .menu .item-466 ul li").removeClass("highlight");
});

 $("#nav .item-470").mouseover(function(){
 $("#selector").addClass("item-470-selector");
 $("#nav .menu .current ul li").css("display", "none");
 $("#nav .menu .active ul li").css("display", "none");
 $("#nav .menu .item-470 ul li").addClass("highlight");
});
 $("#nav .item-470").mouseout(function(){
 $("#selector").removeClass("item-470-selector");
 $("#nav .menu .current ul li").css("display", "inline");
  $("#nav .menu .active ul li").css("display", "inline");
 $("#nav .menu .item-470 ul li").removeClass("highlight");
});
$("#nav .item-472").mouseover(function(){
 $("#selector").addClass("item-472-selector");
 $("#nav .menu .current ul li").css("display", "none");
 $("#nav .menu .active ul li").css("display", "none");
 $("#nav .menu .item-472 ul li").addClass("highlight");
});
$("#nav .item-472").mouseout(function(){
 $("#selector").removeClass("item-472-selector");
 $("#nav .menu .current ul li").css("display", "inline");
  $("#nav .menu .active ul li").css("display", "inline");
 $("#nav .menu .item-472 ul li").removeClass("highlight");
});

$("#nav .item-473").mouseover(function(){
 $("#selector").addClass("item-473-selector");
 $("#nav .menu .current ul li").css("display", "none");
 $("#nav .menu .active ul li").css("display", "none");
   $("#nav .menu .item-473 ul li").addClass("highlight");
});
$("#nav .item-473").mouseout(function(){
 $("#selector").removeClass("item-473-selector");
 $("#nav .menu .current ul li").css("display", "inline");
 $("#nav .menu .active ul li").css("display", "inline");
 $("#nav .menu .item-473 ul li").removeClass("highlight");
});

$("#nav .item-474").mouseover(function(){
 $("#selector").addClass("item-474-selector");
 $("#nav .menu .current ul li").css("display", "none");
 $("#nav .menu .active ul li").css("display", "none");
 $("#nav .menu .item-474 ul li").addClass("highlight");
});
$("#nav .item-474").mouseout(function(){
 $("#selector").removeClass("item-474-selector");
 $("#nav .menu .current ul li").css("display", "inline");
 $("#nav .menu .active ul li").css("display", "inline");
 $("#nav .menu .item-474 ul li").removeClass("highlight");
});
});

</script>
```

My CSS:

```
<style>
#nav .menu li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
float: left;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 10px 16px;
margin-left: 3px;
}

.highlight {
display: inline!important;
}
</style>
```

The HTML is structured like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li class="item-466 active">Page 1</li>
    <ul>
        <li>SubPage1</li>
        <li>SubPage2</li>
        <li>SubPage3</li>
    </ul>
<li class="item-470">Page 2</li>
<li class="item-472">Page 3</li>
<li class="item-473">Page 4</li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: #selector is controlling the arrow beneath the navigation. I removed the rest of the code dealing with #selector because it doesn't have anything to do with the hiding and showing of the sub-menus. Sorry for the confusion. I should have removed it there. I didn't want you all to have to wade through a lot of irrelevant code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the fact that you are using mouseover. When the mouse goes over an element nested within the top level LI it's not actually 'over' the parent element anymore (its over the children), so it sends the mouseout, but the mouse over bubbles up from the child element to the parent LI, which makes it flicker back into it's mouseover state.

**Try looking into mouseenter and mouseleave as opposed to mouseover and mouseout.**

Also, the problem is also apparent in browsers other than just IE - I'm seeing it Chrome as well, but it's to be expected.

**EDIT:** Just looked at the page again in Chrome and I'm not seeing the flicker, not sure if you changed it or it's just being all around quirky. Anyhow, hope my answer helps.

Comment: Thanks Derek, I should have mentioned I've already tried mouseenter and mouseleave as well. I get the same issues.

Comment: You know, now that I look at it closer, I notice the flickering only occurs when your large banner image transitions to 'Test Title 3'...when its on Test Title 1 or 2, I don't see the issue. Most likely, there's some conflicts happening between your nav and your image slider/fader area.

Comment: Darek in regards to your edit, the only reason you're not seeing the flicker on Chrome is probably because Chrome is so fast you don't notice it. But it's there, and the issue is exactly as you described, mouseenter/mouseleave solves his problem